# How to change UIImageView's subview's frame

Tags: iphone

I have UIImageView with subviews. How can I change frames of subviews after rotation UIImageView? I need your help)

Answer (score 0):

If your subView is called view1, do something like this:

```
view1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
```